# SpringBoot 2.3.5 actuator different port causes FileNotFoundException: /dev/management_stdout

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

## Requirement

- We need to change the actuator endpoints to be on a different port number
- Changing the value of `management.server.port: 8404` causes an exception as the server configures the new port to stream logs to `/dev/management_stdout` when it should be `/dev/stdout` (already configured for the server).

## SpringBoot 2.3.5 Setup

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        // For src/gradle/tests.gradle
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
}
```

## Changing SpringBoot Actuator

- Changed the port number as follows in `application.yaml`

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  server:
    port: 8404
```

## Error shown during bootstrap

- The default logger is trying to write to `/dev/management_stdout`

```
2020-11-15T17:23:41 ERROR [app=parking-plus-service,prf=default][tid=,sid=,sxp=][cid=] 77926 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve  : Failed to open access log file [/dev/management_stdout]

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/management_stdout (Operation not permitted)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:291)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:234)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration.onApplicationEvent(ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration.onApplicationEvent(ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at cash.super_.platform.service.ParkingPlusApplication.main(ParkingPlusApplication.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

## Question

- Which property sets the file name prefix `stdout` just like on the server settings shown below?

  - Maybe the management embedded tomcat is taking the value of `directory` and using the prefix as `management_stdout` as the value of the file?

```yaml
server:
  #port: 8080 default
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
      directory: /dev
      prefix: stdout
      buffered: false
      suffix:
      file-date-format:
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for **version 2.3.5** :

Open your application.properties or application.yml file.

Add or modify the following property to specify the log file location:

For application.properties:

```
logging.file=/dev/stdout
```

For application.yml:

```
logging:
  file: /dev/stdout
```

By explicitly setting the log file to /dev/stdout, you ensure that the logs are streamed to the standard output, which is what you want.

Save the changes and restart your application.

Comment: Will it affect both management and the app logs? how would they go to different files? is this on 2.3.5 or newer versions? can you please specify in your answer?

Comment: It is in 2.3.5 version.